# importlib.reload() and exec() in Python

Tags: python, string, import, exec, reload

This is going to be a bit complicated, but bear with me.

I'm having a bit of trouble with reload. I am running unittests in Python through a GUI, and I want to be able to make changes to the tests without having to restart the application.

To do so, I'm trying to use importlib.reload. However, importlib.reload needs a module as an argument and I can only access the imported module names as strings. To bypass that problem, I'm trying to use exec() as seen below:

```
def loadSuite(testModules):

  # Initialize the test suite
  suite = unittest.TestSuite()

  alreadyImported = sorted(sys.modules.keys())
  # For the unit tests for each control module found in testModules
  for t in testModules:
    if t in alreadyImported:
      exec("importlib.reload " + "(" + t + ")")
    suite.addTests(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(t))
  return suite
```

The tests are divided in subdirectories by applications like so:
  Root Program Directory\Application1\Test1

My approach seems to work fine if the reloaded file is located in the main folder. Here's the problem: importlib.reload() sometimes has issues with subdirectories. If I try to run my code with

```
t = "Application1.Test1"
exec("importlib.reload " + "(" + t + ")")
```

I get

> NameError: name 'Application1' is not defined

This is likely because it's trying to treat Application1 as a module and Test1 as a part of it.
However! If I run the same code directly in the terminal, it works.

Where do I even begin to try and fix this?

Comment: what is your application tree (folders, `__init__.py` files, ...)?

Comment: It's not a solution for your question but perhaps for your needs. I had also tests to run that were differing dynamically. I choose an approach with configuration files in order to not reload some code.

Comment: Why do you need `exec`? Just do `importlib.reload(sys.modules[modulename])`

Comment: Why are you doing `alreadyImported = sorted(sys.modules.keys())`? You can check dict key existence with `if t in sys.modules`. It'll be a lot faster, since it can use the hash for a quick lookup instead of going through keys one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing each name with the keys in sys.modules. But the *values* in that dictionary are the modules themselves, which you should be able to pass to reload().

```
if t in alreadyImported:
    importlib.reload(sys.modules[t])
```

Comment: Thanks! That was surprisingly simple, after all. Could have saved me a lot of work if I had checked that earlier..